# wordpress - how can i have a single category postings (just one category news) instead all in the mainpage

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a website, here is the [link](http://harta.net) for reference and visualization, made with wordpress twentyfourteen theme. Currently, in the main page, the main area have blog posting from all categories (currently news and featured). How can I limit it to list only "news" category ? the reason is I dont want to mix it with featured, so that featured is only listed on the right sidebar.

Here is a screenshot for better understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to do this, but you can go to Page (or Post) settings and choose if you want to show this page/post manually.

Checkboxes inside page/post settings (check or uncheck):

1. Featured posts
2. Newest posts

Also, I recommend to watch tutorial how to hide it in this way:
[Source](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-fix-featured-images-appearing-twice-in-wordpress-posts/)